# Using blank-line delimited records and colon-separated fields in awk

Tags: awk, etl

I'd like to be able to work with a file in `awk` where records are separated by a blank line and each field consists of a name followed by a colon, some optional whitespace to be ignored/discarded, followed by a value.  E.g.

```
Name: Smith, John
Age: 42

Name: Jones, Mary
Age: 38

Name: Mills, Pat
Age: 62
```

I understand that I can use `RS=""` to have `awk` understand the blank-lines as record separators and `FS="\n"` to split the fields properly.  However, I'd like to then create an array of `name`→`value` pairs that I can use for further processing of the form

```
if a["Age"] > 40 {print a["Name"]}
```

The order is *usually* consistent, but since it would be dumped in an associative array, the incoming order shouldn't matter or be assumed consistent.

How can I transform the data into an `awk` associative array with the least fuss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1

We use `split` to split each field into two parts: the key and the value.  From these, we create associative array `a`:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS=  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,arr,/: /); a[arr[1]]=arr[2];} if (a["Age"]+0>40) print a["Name"];}' file
Smith, John
Mills, Pat
```

#### Method 2

Here, we split fields at *either* a colon or a newline.  Then, we know that the odd numbered fields are keys and the even ones the values:

```
$ awk -F':|\n' -v RS=  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {a[$i]=$(i+1);} if (a["Age"]+0>40) print a["Name"];}' file
 Smith, John
 Mills, Pat
```

#### Improvement

Is there a chance that any record will be missing a value?  If so, we should clear the array `a` between each record.  In GNU awk, this is easy.  We just add a delete statement:

```
awk -F':|\n' -v RS=  '{delete a; for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {a[$i]=$(i+1);} if (a["Age"]+0>40) print a["Name"];}' file
```

For other awks, you may be required to delete the array one element at a time like:

```
for (k in a) delete a[k];
```

Comment: `delete array` is now POSIX so no longer gawk-specific.

Comment: I went for a combination of your Method 1 with your `delete a` improvement which did just what I needed. Thanks to you and to Ed Morton for checking that `delete array` is now POSIX.